# Hide a row from rendering without filtering?

Tags: tabulator

I would like to do something like Grouping with a bottomRowCalc but having the visibility of the rows of data being optional. Currently I'm using getData('active') to add up the values and row.update() on the "sum" row with the values. But if I filter out the data rows, they wont appear in the getData('active'), so I'd have do a getData().forEach(row => {}) and manually check for another field flag I guess to see if it should be included in the sum.

It sure would be nice if I could continue to use getData('active') but set row.visibility(false) on rows I dont want to show, but still be in *active* ?

Answer (score 0):

Is answering your own question a sin ?
Anyway, for posterity, in case anyone else wants to do this :

```
rowFormatter:function(row) {
    let display = 'inline-block';
    if (some_condition) display= 'none';
    row.getElement().style.display = display;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    rowFormatter: function(row){
        var row_data= row.getData()
        console.log('row_data is...',row_data);
        if (row_data === 'yes'){
            const children = row.getElement().childNodes;
            children.forEach((child) => {
                child.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
                })
        }

        else (row_data === 'Upcomming')
        {   let display = 'inline-block';
            display= 'none';
            row.getElement().style.display = display;
            return true;
        }

    },
```

In this case you will miss s.r. with the row

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).